# How to Clean up my web server (Ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, yocto, bitbake

I am new to Ubuntu and currently trying to get bitbake-toaster to work. 
If I try to start toaster via the terminal, the following message appears:

```
Warning: bitbake appears to be dead, but the Toaster web server is running.
 Something fishy is going on.
Cleaning up the web server to start from a clean slate.
```

How can I clean up the web server to get rid of this error message? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is how I got rid of the error message.

In your build folder there should be a .toastermain.pid file which contains the PID of the toaster server. Kill the toaster server using`kill pid_of_toaster_server`. Then restart toaster